# How can i add a string with an integer in bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix, integer

I want to read a random txt which contains some random integers in this form:

```
2:10

4:4

10:15

22:5
```

Then i want to find the sum of each column . Firstly , i thought of spliting each line like if every line is a string:

```
columnA="$(cut -d':' -f1 <<<$line)"
columnB="$(cut -d':' -f2 <<<$line)"
```

columnAcontains the elements of the first column and columnB the elements of the second one  . Then i created a variable sumA=0 and i tried to take the sum of each column like that:

```
sumA=$((columnA+sumA))
```

I am getting the result i want but with this message as well

**")syntax error: operand expected (error token is "**

Same for the second column :

```
sumB=$((columnB+sumB))
```

The time i am getting this error and i dont get the result i want:
**")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "**

This is the code in general :

```
sumA=0
sumB=0

while IFS= read -r line
do

columnA="$(cut -d':' -f1 <<<$line)"
sumA=$((columnA+sumA))

columnB="$(cut -d':' -f2 <<<$line)"
sumB=$((columnB+sumB))

done < "random.txt"

echo $sumA
echo $sumB
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your syntax.

Comment: Your code should work for the described input file `random.txt`. Does not your actual input file contain decimal numbers?

Comment: Probably it is because you have empty lines in your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be simplified just to

```
awk -F: '{sumA+=$1; sumB+=$2} END {printf "%s\n%s\n", sumA, sumB}' random.txt
```

From the manual:

```
$ man awk

...
-F fs
--field-separator fs
    Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).
...
```

Comment: Perfect thank you a lot!

Comment: Can you explain what awk -F does? and why you chose to use it

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΓιαννάκος `man awk` : "`-F fs  --field-separator fs  Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).`"

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΓιαννάκος My fail. Forgot about `+=` operator. `var_a=var_a+var_b` is equal to `var_a+=var_b` It is even shorter.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "cut" use built in  bash references: "${variable}"

```
ColumnA=0
ColumnB=0
while read l
do
ColumnA=$((${l//:*}+$ColumnA))
ColumnB=$((${l//*:}+$ColumnB))
done < random.txt
echo $ColumnA $ColumnB
```

Comment: same error as mine